# Search through long list in android

Tags: android, mysql, csv

I am a beginner in android programming and I am trying to create a math 24 game which player use basic arithmetic operator to get 24 from the value of 4 randomly drawn cards

I have created the game but then realised i forgot to eliminate the unsolvable cases like 1 1 1 1 (four aces)

I was searching for best way to eliminate these cases and i found that the list of [solvable is only around a thousand cases](http://www.4nums.com/solutions/allsolvables/) so i can do a simple search and see if the card combination is in the solvable set.

I am new to android and programming in general, so would like to seek advice on the best way of doing this. Should i be using a CSV file and search? or using mySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution imo:  draw/create 4 random cards, check to see mathematically if there's a solution, if not discard hand, and draw/create 4 more.

It's the same outcome as drawing 4 cards, and checking to see if that combo is blacklisted in some database, without needing a database.  It's probably like thousand times faster too.

The only problem I would see is if your definition of random meant something other than drawing from a full deck every round.  But you'll run into problems as well with those other methods too, since no matter what you're restricting the random sequences that are allowed.